# How to get stats for individual process/thread in SLURM?

Tags: performance, monitoring, hpc, slurm

How do I monitor each of running threads/processes from my job? Basically, I would want to see an output similar to what is given by `top`, or `ps`: such as CPU usage per thread, memory usage by process, etc..

In SLURM, there is the command `sstat`, in which I can check the **job stats**. For instance, it allows me to check what is the total CPU time (user+system), RSS, and even CPU frequency requested by the submitted job. It does not include a detailed **per process** (or thread) information.

Answer (score 0):

TO get process-level information, you can activate the `AcctGatherProfileType/hdf5` plugin that will allow you to collect a lot of metrics into time series packed in a [HDF5](https://support.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/) file. See this [page](https://slurm.schedmd.com/hdf5_profile_user_guide.html) for more information.